# JUnit assertions within in Java 8 stream

Tags: java, junit, java-stream

Say I have three objects that I save to the database and set the db generated ID into. I don't know the order of the objects returned from the method `saveToDb`. But I want to junit test that those generated IDs are there. How do I do that within in stream? I want to do something like this:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = getObjects();
numRecords = saveToDb(myObjects); // numRecords=3
List<Integer> intArray = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
intArray.stream()
  .forEach(it -> myObjects.stream()
    .filter(it2 -> it2.getId().equals(it))
    .????
```

But I'm not sure where my `assertEquals()` would go in a statement like this. Or is my approach all wrong? I know I could use a simple for-loop, but I like the elegance of streams. Additionally, is there a way to dynamically create the intArray, in case I have more than 3 myObjects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems (if i understood correctly), how about something like this:

```
 boolean result = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream()
            .allMatch(i -> objects
                .stream()
                .map(MyObject::getId)
                .filter(j -> j == i).findAny().isPresent());
    Assert.assertTrue(result);
```

Comment: @user1660256 doesn't this test each individual id? like in the question you just posted?

Comment: Yes, it does! I accepted the other answer before I saw this.

Comment: @user1660256 in this case, delete the other question plz

Comment: Just one point of clarification before I delete the other question: Would I have to open a stream and map & test each attribute individually? I have more than just the ID to test for.

Comment: @user1660256 there are other ways, like sorting them and then compare and a for loop, etc. Since these are tests only, I wouldn't care...

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to check whether a MyObject instance was assigned an ID?
Is the equalness to the IDs in the array from any importance?

If not:

```
List<MyObject> objects = getObjects();
saveToDb(objects);
objects.stream().map(MyObject::getId).forEach(Assert::assertNotNull);
```

Assuming there is a "getId" Method on MyObject of course.

Comment: Thanks, but yes, I would like to assert that the ID is equal to the ID I'm expecting.

Comment: Then again, I guess the actual value of the ID doesn't really matter, so I'm going to accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a little supplement for your additional question:

> Additionally, is there a way to dynamically create the intArray, in case I have more than 3 myObjects?

Yes you can use `IntStream` to create  a stream based on the size of your objects like:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, objects.size()) // both start and end inclusive
```

and there's also a method `IntStream.range(int start, int end)` which `end` is exclusive.