# JUnit Testing for attribute values within in Stream

Tags: java, junit, java-stream

This question is related to my previous question at [JUnit assertions within in Java 8 stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092438/junit-assertions-within-in-java-8-stream/43092730#43092730).

If I have 3 objects, how do I verify the values of the objects' attributes within a stream? My previous question answered how to test for the presence of them, but I now need to test for each individual attribute's value. Can someone give me a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the properties by the expected values and count the resulting entries. This number must be equal to the original size.

```
List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
long count = objects.stream()
    .map(MyObject::getId)
    .filter(id -> expected.contains(id.intValue()))
    .count();
Assert.assertEquals(objects.size(), (int) count);
```

If you want to check all properties in one stream, do it like this:

```
long count = objects.stream()
    .filter(o-> expectedIds.contains(o.getId().intValue()))
    .filter(o-> expectedNames.contains(o.getName()))
    // and so on
    .count();
```

Comment: I would need to do this for each attribute separately, right? I would like a way to test an object in one statement. Is that possible?

Comment: No, you don't. Don't `map` and filter for each property you want to check, e. g. `.filter(o -> expectedIds.contains(o.getId().intValue()))`

Comment: Hint: I would not check all properties in one stream to validate **which** property is wrong

Comment: Ok, you say don't map & filter for each property, but I don't know what do instead.

Comment: @user1660256 I changed my answer. Does this help?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!!